# Paypal Express checkout not working?

Tags: php, ios, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have been using Paypal Express checkout for payment in my application.Still its in sandbox mode. It was working fine without any problem till last week.But from this week, the transaction ID not generating.

First of all, I will explain my full flow of transaction.

1.When I checkout, I will call the php file in my server with customer detail and products details.

2.Then this php file will call Paypal API and generate a token and send it back to my application.

3.With transaction ID and device token (generated by libPayPalEC.a library) and loading the sandbox paypal URL with these two parameters.Below is the way I am loading URL in webview if I successfully get token from my server.

```
NSString *urlAddress = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&useraction=commit&drt=%@&token=%@",_deviceToken,_payPalToken];
```

4.The webView will be loaded with login page and further transaction is made.

The above process were worked nicely till last week but now its stuck in the second point itself.My php not providing an token.Instead it the response like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:ns1="og" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ns1:xmlns="http://ogp.me/ns#"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!--
         Script info: script: merchantpaymentweb, cmd: &#x5f;express&#x2d;checkout, template: xpt&#x2f;Checkout&#x2f;ec&#x2f;Login, date: Jun&#x20;26&#x2c;&#x20;2013&#x20;08&#x3a;06&#x3a;00&#x20;PDT; country: US, language: en_US, xslt server: 
        web version: 104&#x2e;0&#x2d;6660064 branch: 54acf8f793ee3c83461ce755fea6f9b7ceeea381
        content version: &#x2d;
        pexml version: 104&#x2e;0&#x2d;6561375
        page XSL: Checkout/default/en_US/ec/Login.xsl
       hostname : fbS&#x2e;6KL5lvTqGnDaa&#x2d;D3Z7mrkSj1m0cLx4&#x2d;hBxdfN7U
         rlogid : ukDrJAYX6XpzjZWCm13fDfZSMweU30&#x25;2bmKW&#x25;2bO7bgiwIlt8cKrcoR32LdDR4kzkZZIuUQ690k&#x25;2bI7U&#x25;3d&#x5f;13f84f881b6
-->
<title>Pay with a PayPal account - PayPal</title>
<!--googleoff: all-->
<meta name="description" content="PayPal is the safer, easier way to pay online without revealing your credit card number.">
<!--googleon: all-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"><link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/css/core/xptdev.css"><link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/css/core/global.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/Checkout/css/checkout.css">
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;www&#x2e;sandbox&#x2e;paypal&#x2e;com&#x2f;MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB&#x2d;640&#x2d;20130622&#x2d;1/Checkout/css/ie.css"><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/css/sandbox.css"><style type="text/css" id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style><script type="text/javascript">
                if (self === top) {
                    var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
                    antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
                } else {
                    top.location = self.location;
                }
            </script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/js/lib/min/global.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">PAYPAL.util.lazyLoadRoot = 'https\x3a\x2f\x2fwww\x2esandbox\x2epaypal\x2ecom\x2fMERCHANTPAYMENTWEB\x2d640\x2d20130622\x2d1';</script><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/icon/pp_favicon_x.ico"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/pui/apple-touch-icon.png"></head><body class="xptSandbox"><noscript><style type="text/css">body{display:block !important;}</style><p class="nonjsAlert">PayPal requires JavaScript for many of its features. To check out, please <a target="blank" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/preview/how-to-turn-on-javascript?locale.x=en_US">turn on Javascript in your internet browser</a>.</p></noscript><div class="" id="stdpage"><div id="header"><h1 class="confidential">Benchmark&#x20;iPhone&#x27;s&#x20;Test&#x20;Store</h1></div><hr><div id="content"><div id="headline"><h1 class="accessAid">Choose a way to pay</h1>
</div><div id="messageBox"></div><div id="main"><div class="layout1"><iframe class="hide" id="yui-history-iframe" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/scr_grayDotRepeatBg_3x1.gif"></iframe><input type="hidden" id="yui-history-field" name="yui-history-field" value=""><form id="historyForm" method="get" class="noAnimation" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_flow"><input id="historyDispatch" type="hidden" name="dispatch" value="50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081988da7a3c03e3ee25661350b6a36dba24a"><input id="historySession" type="hidden" name="SESSION"><input type="submit" id="historySubmit" name="historySubmit" value="" class="hide parentSubmit noAnimation"><input name="auth" type="hidden" value="ARlB87oxQ9J5V1AHb1z0XwiBtbOHOHDRWmiu&#x2e;ySH5Pdx06UHFSnnO&#x2e;ZzwT93TLFLx"><input name="form_charset" type="hidden" value="UTF&#x2d;8"></form><div class="accessAid" id="swapPanel"></div><div class="accessAid" id="babySlider"></div><form method="post" id="parentForm" name="login_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081988da7a3c03e3ee25661350b6a36dba24a" class=""><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_flow"><input type="hidden" id="myAllTextSubmitID" name="myAllTextSubmitID" value=""><input type="hidden" id="miniPager" name="miniPager" value=""><div class="layout2f"><div class="col first"><div class="rounded defaultStyles"><div class="top outer"></div><div class="body outer clearfix"><div class="rounded child"><div class="top inner"></div><div class="body clearfix" id="miniCartContent"><div id="miniCart" class=""><h3>Your&#x20;order&#x20;summary</h3><div class="small head wrap">Descriptions<span class="amount">Amount</span></div><ol class="small wrap items "><li class="seller1"><ul><li id="multiitem1" class="itmdet"><ul class="item1"><li class="dark"><span class="name"><a class="autoTooltip" href="#name0" title="Test&#x20;Product" id="showname0">Test&#x20;Product</a></span><span class="amount">&#x24;2&#x2e;50</span></li><li class="secondary"><span>Item price: &#x24;2&#x2e;50</span></li><li class="secondary">Quantity: 1</li></ul><ul></ul></li></ul></li></ol><div class="wrap items totals item1"><ul><li class="small heavy">Item total <span class="amount">&#x24;2&#x2e;50</span></li></ul></div><div class="small wrap items totals item1"><ul><li class="heavy highlight finalTotal"><span class="grandTotal amount highlight">Total &#x24;2&#x2e;50 AUD</span></li></ul></div><div><div></div><div></div></div></div></div><div class="bottom inner"></div></div></div><div class="bottom outer"></div></div></div><div class="col last"><div class="accessAid" id="panelMask"><div class="top"><div> </div></div><div class="body clearfix"><div><div id="progressMeter"><img border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/icon/icon_animated_prog_dkgy_42wx42h.gif" alt="Loading.."><span class="panelMaskMsg" id="defaultMsg">Loading ...</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="updateCtry">Updating country</span><span class="panelMaskMsg hide" id="loginMsg">Authenticating your information</span><span class="panelMaskMsg hide" id="loginUpdateMsg">Logging you in</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="authMsg">Authenticating your information.</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="authUpdateMsg">Securing your information.</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="reviewMsg">Updating your information ...</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="shippingMsg">Updating your information ...</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="cartMsg">Updating order total ...</span><span class="hide panelMaskMsg" id="processPayment"></span></div></div></div><div class="bottom"><div> </div></div></div><div id="sliderWrapper"><div id="parentSlider"><fieldset id="sliders"><legend class="accessAid">Login</legend><input type="hidden" id="currentSession" name="currentSession" value="hIeXpvxuBcpEkVcO6ac1zxQzgDbkoJ0yBpSa7hB9FsbaJEDJs3mrB2YWy10"><input type="hidden" id="pageState" name="pageState" value="login"><input type="hidden" id="currentDispatch" name="currentDispatch" value="50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081988da7a3c03e3ee25661350b6a36dba24a"><noscript><input type="hidden" id="flag_non_js" name="flag_non_js" value="true"></noscript><div id="loginModule"><div id="hdrContainer" class="subhdr"><h2>Choose a way to pay</h2></div><div class="panel active" id="method-paypal"><div class="top"></div><div class="body clearfix"><div id="secureCheckout" class="lockLogo"><span class="spriteLogo paypallock" title="PayPal"></span></div><span class="downarrow"></span><div class="subhead">Pay with my PayPal account<span class="help">Log in to your account to complete the purchase</span></div><input type="hidden" name="email_recovery" value="false"><input type="hidden" name="password_recovery" value="false"><div id="loginBox"><p class="group"><label for="login_email"><span class="labelText">Email</span></label><span class="field"><input type="text" id="login_email" class="confidential large" name="login_email" value="venkatnskns&#x40;gmail&#x2e;com"></span></p><p class="group"><label for="login_password"><span class="labelText">PayPal password</span></label><span class="field"><input autocomplete="off" type="password" id="login_password" name="login_password" value="" class="restricted large"></span></p><p class="buttons"><input type="submit" id="submitLogin" name="login.x" value="Log In" class="button primary default parentSubmit"><p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_account-recovery&from=PayPal">Forgot your email address or password?</a></p></p></div><input type="hidden" id="pageSession" name="SESSION" value="OdkkP9CI6mk&#x2d;sjRgiWGSF62n&#x2d;GgAqPqVtZrCPVXBG2V1uX6NmTvvMBEx2&#x5f;e"><input type="hidden" id="pageDispatch" name="dispatch" value="50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081988da7a3c03e3ee25661350b6a36dba24a"><input type="hidden" id="CONTEXT_CGI_VAR" name="CONTEXT" value="wtgSziM4C5x0SI&#x2d;9CmKcv2vkSeTLK5P&#x5f;g6HqzC&#x5f;&#x5f;YTYkcqziFNcB84p79Ja"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div><div id="method-cc" class="panel scTrack:xpt&#x2f;Checkout&#x2f;ec&#x2f;Login&#x3a;&#x3a;&#x5f;express&#x2d;checkout:ClickBilling"><span class="rightarrow"></span><div class="subhead"><span class="buttonAsLink"><input type="submit" value="Don't have a PayPal account?" id="minipageSubmitBtn" name="new_user_button.x" class="parentSubmit noMask noAnimation"></span><p class="small secondary">(Optional) Join PayPal for faster future checkout</p></div><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_flow"><input type="hidden" name="id" value=""><input type="hidden" name="close_external_flow" value="false"><input type="hidden" name="external_close_account_payment_flow" value="payment_flow"></div></div></fieldset><div class="layout1"><p class="small secondary return"><span class="buttonAsLink"><input type="submit" value="Cancel and return to Benchmark&#x20;iPhone&#x27;s&#x20;Test&#x20;Store." name="cancel_return" class="action"></span></p></div></div><script type="text/javascript">
                                                                    YUD.setStyle('parentSlider', 'margin-left', '-560px');
                                                                </script></div></div></div><input name="auth" type="hidden" value="ARlB87oxQ9J5V1AHb1z0XwiBtbOHOHDRWmiu&#x2e;ySH5Pdx06UHFSnnO&#x2e;ZzwT93TLFLx"><input name="form_charset" type="hidden" value="UTF&#x2d;8"></form></div></div></div><input type="hidden" id="XoCountryCode" name="" value="US"><div id="prefooter"></div><div id="footer"><div id="opinionlab"><a href="javascript:PP_O_LC();">Site Feedback</a> <img src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/sm_333_oo.gif" border="0" alt="Site Feedback"></div>
<!-- OnlineOpinionF3cS v3.0-->
<script type="text/javascript">
            var feedback_link='Site Feedback'; var _ht=escape(document.location.href);
                                                                var _hr=document.referrer;custom_var=escape('ukDrJAYX6XpzjZWCm13fDfZSMweU30\x252bmKW\x252bO7bgiwIlt8cKrcoR32LdDR4kzkZZIuUQ690k\x252bI7U\x253d\x5f13f84f881b6')+'|';custom_var+='Unknown|xpt\x2fCheckout\x2fec\x2fLogin\x3a\x3a\x5fexpress\x2dcheckout|US|en_US|Unknown|79933151TE8175237';// Paypal Custom URL class
            var PayPalURL = function(pagename) {
                this.language_country_code = "en_US";
                this.dd = "US";
                this.nn = "00";this.pagename = escape(pagename.replace(/\s|\//g, "_"));
                this.to_str = function() {

                return "https://"+this.dd+".paypal.com/"+this.language_country_code+"/"+this.nn+"/"+this.pagename+".page"
                }
                }
                var paypal_url = new PayPalURL("xpt\x2fCheckout\x2fec\x2fLogin\x3a\x3a\x5fexpress\x2dcheckout");
            // Below gives you the ability to change the other properties after the object is created
            //paypal_url.dd="ES";
            //paypal_url.nn="01";

        _ht = paypal_url.to_str();
        var _ht_temp=_ht;
        var _hr_temp=_hr;
        var baseurl="https://www\x2esandbox\x2epaypal\x2ecom\x2fus/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_handle-sf-redirect";var custom_var_temp=custom_var;</script><p>PayPal. The safer, easier way to pay. For more information, read our <a target="_blank" href="https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/UserAgreement_popup&locale.x=en_US" title="Opens in new window" onClick="PAYPAL.core.openWindow(event, {width: 640, height:500});">User Agreement</a> and <a target="_blank" href="https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/Privacy_popup&locale.x=en_US" title="Opens in new window" onClick="PAYPAL.core.openWindow(event, {width: 640, height:500});">Privacy Policy</a>.</p></div><div id="footerSandbox"><div id="sandboxFooter"><div class="nav-footer"></div><div id="testsite"><h1>Test Site</h1></div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/Checkout/js/min/widgets.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var mcSequenceDuration = "200";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/Checkout/js/min/checkout.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/Checkout/js/login.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/js/tns/fso_ngxo.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">PAYPAL.tns.loginflow = 'xpt\x2fCheckout\x2fec\x2fLogin';PAYPAL.tns.flashLocation = 'https\x3a\x2f\x2fwww\x2esandbox\x2epaypal\x2ecom/en_US/m/mid.swf';</script>
<!-- SiteCatalyst Code
Copyright 1997-2005 Omniture, Inc.
More info available at http://www.omniture.com -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20130622-1/js/site_catalyst/pp_jscode_paypalsandboxdev.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
s.prop1="xpt\x2fCheckout\x2fec\x2fLogin";
s.prop20="1372325446";
s.prop35="out";
s.prop40="9bf35c68eb041";
s.prop50="en_US";
s.prop64="b114448342636";
s.eVar28="tnc\x2d9\x2decg\x2dcntl2";
s.eVar31="xpt\x2fCheckout\x2fec\x2fLogin\x3a\x3a\x5fexpress\x2dcheckout";
s.eVar50="ukDrJAYX6XpzjZWCm13fDfZSMweU30\x252bmKW\x252bO7bgiwIlt8cKrcoR32LdDR4kzkZZIuUQ690k\x252bI7U\x253d\x5f13f84f881b6";
s.pageName="xpt\x2fCheckout\x2fec\x2fLogin\x3a\x3a\x5fexpress\x2dcheckout";
s.prop56="yes";
s.prop21="EC\x2d87714847AX7819342";
s.prop5="79933151TE8175237";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
function scOnload(){var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code);}
if(window.addEventListener){
window.addEventListener('load',scOnload,false);
}else if(window.attachEvent){
window.attachEvent('onload', scOnload);
};
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
//-->
</script><noscript><img
src="//paypal.112.2O7.net/b/ss/paypalsandboxdev/1/H.6--NS/0?pageName=NonJavaScript"
height="1" width="1" border="0" alt="" /></noscript>
<!--/DO NOT REMOVE/-->

<!-- End SiteCatalyst Code -->
</body></html>
```

We didn't made any change in the code(both in app and server). We have three applications like using same sandbox account but using three different severs.In all three applications its not working now.We don't know what is the exact problem. We have been searching in google and paypal site for past two days and came up with no solution.

Please suggest your idea.Really it would be a great help for us now.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:**

In my php code(main part)

```
   if( $ack == "SUCCESS" ) {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);

            //Store the order information the DB and get the last inserted id
            $lastInsertOrderId = storeOrder($token,$comments,$transcation);

            //Store the order items array in the database
            storeOrderItems( $_POST["productArray"],  $lastInsertOrderId);


            //   echo urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
                /* XML Response */
                //$ResponseXML ="<Main><Token><![CDATA[" .$token. "]]></Token></Main>";
                /* JSON Response */
                $ResponseXML ='{"Token":"' .$token. '"}';

               echo $ResponseXML;
                   //If I command the following 4 lines I can get the token but I can't proceed the transaction.
               Redirect to paypal.com here
               $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
               $payPalURL = PAYPAL_URL.$token;
               header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
                  }
```

In the above php code if I command the last 4 lines I can get the Paypal token but while loading the sandbox login page, its saying the below error.

"This transaction is invalid .Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."

Please share your ideas.

Thank you....

Comment: Just wondering, have you found a solution for this? We are seeing the same issue on IE only.